# Why does React protected route works for the 2nd time with Recoil state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, recoiljs

I'm building a small Recipe app with Recoil and React Router (Typescript for both).
My goal is to set a Boolean as 'loginState' with  Recoil, as indication for a Protected Route component to be ready to navigate.

I'm trying to set **useSetRecoilState** loginState to true in Onboarding component, and redirect to route,  but by the time recoil state will be updated, **ProtectedRoute** component will redirect back to entry page, since **loginState** will be false ( as sounds reasonable).

Hence it will work only at the 2nd time, ill click it.
Does the right solution for keep auth needs to be on localStorage? or do i need to wait somehow for recoil to update **loginState**.

I'm using also the [DebugObserver](https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/dev-tools/) recoil suggested to check state updates logs.

Below is my code:

store.ts

```
export const loginState = atom({
    key: "loginState",
    default: false, 
});
```

Onboarding.ts ( set true on an atom onClick, and redirects to '/main' route)

```
const Onboarding = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const setLogin = useSetRecoilState(loginState);

    return (
        <div className="Onboarding">
            <div className="DishesContainer">
                <img src={Dishes} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="description">
                <h2>Start Cooking</h2>
                <p className="p1">Let’s join our community
                    to cook better food!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className="GetStartedContainer">
                <AppButton text="Get Started" onClick={() => {
                    setLogin(true);
                    history.push("/main");
                }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

ProtectedRoute.ts

```
export const ProtectedRoute = (props: RouteProps) => {
    const isLoggedIn = useRecoilValue(loginState);
    const authenticationPath = "/";
    
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        return <Route {...props} />;
    } else {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: authenticationPath }} />;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with recoil, but is the state not initialized to anything when the app mounts? Can you share how these components are rendered in the routes?\

Comment: Well recoil has a <RecoilRoot> wrapper above the app, and when the app loads all the atoms are initialized, so its fine for that manner.

Answer (score 0):

State updates are asynchronous, this is true for Recoils `useState` as well as for recoils state updates.

You call

```js
setLogin(true);
history.push("/main");
```

on your button click, but when the new route is pushed to the router, the loginState is likely to still be set to `false`. Since you cannot know when the `setLogin` call resolves to a new render with the new state (which will especially be true for React 18, because of concurrent rendering enabled by default), you have to use a `useEffect` which triggers when `loginState` changes, like so:

```
const Onboarding = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useRecoilState(loginState);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        history.push("/main");
      }
    }, [isLoggedIn]);

    return (
        <div className="Onboarding">
            <div className="DishesContainer">
                <img src={Dishes} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="description">
                <h2>Start Cooking</h2>
                <p className="p1">Let’s join our community
                    to cook better food!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className="GetStartedContainer">
                <AppButton text="Get Started" onClick={() => {
                    setLogin(true);
                }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```